# SQL ORDER BY 1st column, but if 1st column is empty replace the empty value by a value from 2nd column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table with several columns, two of which are the start and the finish time of an event. The query pulls rows from the table and sorts it by the start time - the finish time is irrelevant for the sorting.
However in rare cases, there might be an entry without a start time. In this case I want the query to handle it like the start time would be the same value as the finish time, so it isn't placed at the beginning of the table:

Example Data:

```
|   Start  |  Finish  |
| -------- | -------- |
| 15:31:00 | 15:39:00 |  1st Event
| 00:00:00 | 15:36:00 |  2nd Event
| 15:37:00 | 15:42:00 |  3rd Event
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT FROM table ORDER BY Start ASC
```

Obviously what happens now is, that the 2nd Event (with an empty start time) will end up on top or at the bottom of the list, depending on ASC or DESC argument.

What I want is it to be put in the list as if the start time would also be 15:36:00. As if there was a function to say

```
If Start is '00:00:00'
then Start = Finish
```

Doing a COALESCE like

```
SELECT FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(Start, Finish)
```

is not an option, because events have different lengths and in this example, the finish time of event 2 is before the finish time of event 1 so it would still end up at the beginning of the list.

Any way to do this directly within the SQL Query?

Best regards!

Comment: without an immutable sort criterion, you can't do that. How do you determine that the row you with the NULL start time is the second and not the first event? I mean, if you know already that the row with a NULL start time is the second event - you could simply think that your comment is actually a descriptive column - and order by that.

Answer (score 1):

You may order using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Start <> '00:00:00' THEN Start ELSE `End` END;
```

Note that `END` is a keyword in MySQL and so you should avoid naming your columns using it.

Comment: `Finish` might be a nice alternative for `End`. Also, I know it makes little difference, but for readability I prefer: `CASE WHEN Start = '00:00:00' THEN Finish ELSE Start END`.

Comment: Yeah however then the 2nd event would still end up before the 1st event, because its end time is sooner than the end time of event 1.

Comment: Yeah this is only bad translation from German. My columns are titled in German so no confusion there with the term "End".

Comment: @Soaring211 There is no way to guess what that missing value should be, sans some other columns which can be used.  Maybe sorting on the finish time, assuming it always be present, would be a better option for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There's no need to guess. I just want to trick the system into thinking the start time of event 2 was 15:36:00.